# User Defined Function To Run Once When Input Changes

Tags: r, shiny

I am pretty new to R and Shiny dashboards. I created as user defined function to run percentile analysis based on a specific category I am selecting on the Shiny Dashboard via a selectizeInput. The function returns 10 items as output between tables and graphs. I am trying to find a way to refresh the function only once when the input changes and call the 10 items as opposed to running the function 10 times for each of the outputs in the list. I tried to recreate a small example below:

USER DEFINED FUNCTION

GetPercentileAnalysis(GroupName)

```
GetPercentileAnalysis=function(GroupName){

(...)

list(output1,output2,output3)

}
```

In shiny I am currently creating the output as follows:

```
output$output1<-renderPlotly({
   GroupName<-input$GroupNameInput
   GetPercentileAnalysis(GroupName)[[1]]
})

output$output2<-renderPlotly({
   GroupName<-input$GroupNameInput
   GetPercentileAnalysis(GroupName)[[2]]
}) 

output$output3<-renderPlotly({
   GroupName<-input$GroupNameInput
   GetPercentileAnalysis(GroupName)[[3]]
})
```

The problem that the function will run 3 times. Is there a way to define the function and make it run once and extrapolate the outputs? Apologies if this sounds like a really dumb question but any help would be expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `reactive` to compute the data:

```r
my_reactive <- reactive({
   GroupName<-input$GroupNameInput
   GetPercentileAnalysis(GroupName)
})
```

Then use it in the plots

```r
output$output1<-renderPlotly(my_reactive()[[1]])

output$output2<-renderPlotly(my_reactive()[[2]])

output$output3<-renderPlotly(my_reactive()[[3]])
})
```